# Why can't I save my scraped html table to pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a python script that scrapes a html table. When I try to save my scraped data to pandas dataframe, I get an error. Please help me check what am doing wrong?

Here is my codeblock

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
import time
import pandas as pd

def HDI():
    url = 'https://worldpopulationreview.com/country-rankings/hdi-by-country'

    service = Service(executable_path="C:/driver/new/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe")
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(5)

    btn = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, '_3p_1XEZR')
    btn.click()
    time.sleep(5)

    temp_height=0

    while True:
        #Looping down the scroll bar
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,500)")
        #sleep and let the scroll bar react
        time.sleep(5)
        #Get the distance of the current scroll bar from the top
        check_height = driver.execute_script("return document.documentElement.scrollTop || window.window.pageYOffset || document.body.scrollTop;")
        #If the two are equal to the end
        if check_height==temp_height:
           break
        temp_height=check_height
    time.sleep(3)

    row_headers = []
    tableheads = driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME, 'datatable-th')
    for value in tableheads:
        thead_values = value.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, 'has-tooltip-bottom').text.strip()

        row_headers.append(thead_values)

    tablebodies = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')
    for row in tablebodies:
        tabledata = row.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tr, td')

        row_data = []
        for data in tabledata:
            row_data.append(data.text)

    df = pd.DataFrame(row_data, columns=row_headers)
    df 

HDI()
```

Here is the error i get

```
File "c:\Users\LP\Documents\python\HD1 2023\HDI2023.py", line 49, in HDI
df = pd.DataFrame(row_data, columns=row_headers)
File "C:\Users\LP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 351, in ndarray_to_mgr
_check_values_indices_shape_match(values, index, columns)
File "C:\Users\LP\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py", line 422, in _check_values_indices_shape_match
  raise ValueError(f"Shape of passed values is {passed}, indices imply {implied}")
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (9, 1), indices imply (9, 9)
```

I want to save the above scraped values into pandas dataframe. That's my aim. Please help if you can. THANKS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your variable `row_data` you are only saving one row and you are overwriting it in every iteration. You probably want to use all rows in your DataFrame. You can for example create a new variable `row_data_all` and pass that to your DataFrame

```py
row_data_all = []
for row in tablebodies:
    tabledata = row.find_elements(selenium.webdriver.common.by.By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'tr, td')

    row_data = []
    for data in tabledata:
        row_data.append(data.text)
    row_data_all.append(row_data)

pd.DataFrame(row_data_all, columns = row_headers)
```

In case you really wanted to create a DataFrame from a single row you should use

```py
pd.DataFrame(row_data, index = row_headers).T
```

### Alternative

You can also use pandas' `read_html()` method, which only needs the html source code. You can even pass it the source code of the entire page, and it will return a list of DataFrames of the tables found in the source code. This will also speed up your function a lot.

```py
html_table = driver.find_element(By.TAG_NAME, "table").get_attribute("outerHTML")
df = pd.read_html(html_table)[0]
```

Comment: yeah it does. thanks genius